# android studio - manifest doesn't seem to update with icon files

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to add an icon to my app. I'm not sure if I've done it right, but I can see the different files on the left hand side, but the manifest doesn't seem to realise that they're there.

I'm sure I'm making a stupid mistake somewhere - Anyone know where?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: When I run the app, I get this in console (as expected) -

> Error:(11) error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.peakevans.localadmin.notificationfaker:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
>   Error:(11) error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.peakevans.localadmin.notificationfaker:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
>   Error:(11) resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.peakevans.localadmin.notificationfaker:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
>   Error:(11) resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.peakevans.localadmin.notificationfaker:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
>   Error:failed processing manifest.

[image: Screenshot of manifest]

Comment: just run the app

Comment: clean and rebuild it

Answer (score 1):

with [this](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.15&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(96%2C%20125%2C%20139)&crop=1&backgroundShape=none&effects=none&name=ic_launcher) site make your icons and copy and replace icons in the mipmap folders. chage your project view in left hand side and you can see mipmap folders.
[image]